# How to Pull to the top a Bootstrap Column using vertical offset?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, offset

I'm using bootstrap and i'm trying to make the top left column the one with the id= "related-items-box" the same size as the other three columns. If those columns with the ID's top, middle and bottom get bigger, the one on the left will have the same size to all the 4 columns look like a big rectangle.

This is what i'm trying to get:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDBwH.png)

And this is what I Have:

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE1eG.png)

This is the Source Code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row show-grid">
          <div class="col-md-8" id="related-items-box">.col-md-8</div>
          <div class="col-md-4" id="top">.col-md-4 col-md-offset-8</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8" id="middle">.col-md-4 col-md-offset-8</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8" id="bottom">.col-md-4 col-md-offset-8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row show-grid">
          <div class="col-md-12">.col-md-12</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for...

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row show-grid">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" id="related-items-box"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" id="top"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" id="middle"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" id="bottom"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row show-grid">
          <div class="col-md-12">.col-md-12</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/beardedmike/5o5m3wrs/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row show-grid">
      <div class="col-md-8" id="related-items-box">.col-md-8</div>
      <div class="col-md-4" id="top">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12"></div>
             <div class="col-md-12"></div>
             <div class="col-md-12"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row show-grid">
      <div class="col-md-12">.col-md-12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I just tried it and It kind of looks like what i'm trying to get but the issue is that if I use another row it will start on the second line. and with this approach having the <div class="col-md-4" id="top"> on the first row will add it to the back and it's not necessary.

Comment: Can you please clarify? I didn't understand the question.